# How can I write byte array in Dart?

Tags: java, flutter, dart

How do I write a byte array in Dart? I want to implement this function, but it is Java code with `byte[]` in it. Can it be written in Dart as well?

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] data) throws Exception {
    try {
        return performCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is `Uint8List`. It is the equivalent of `byte[]` of Java in Dart. Every single value has an equivalent in another language, so `byte[]` in a few languages is like:

1. Java: `byte[]`
2. Dart: `Uint8List`
3. iOS: `FlutterStandardTypedData -> typedDataWithBytes`

I recommend looking at the documentation for more: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#codec